# Does Ruby have a int() like function?

Tags: ruby, python-3.x

Is there something that can do this in Ruby?

```
a = 'astring'[0..[5,'astring'.length].min]
```

Can anything take that string and generate a integer from it? In Python I could use:

```
int(a,36)
```

The output would be "18141102".

Comment: Explan what you want. People not knowing Python cannot guess what you are expecting.

Comment: Agree with @oldergod, but answer is to_i

Comment: As a side note, as far as i can tell [0..[5,'astring'.length].min] can be replaced with [0..5].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Danh said, you are looking for [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i).

```
a.to_i(36)
```

Comment: There's also `Integer(a, 36)`, which has slightly different behavior.